# JUnit Test with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security

I want to test, that I am not authorized to do that. 
Here my code:

```
/* imports */

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class AuthenticationTest {

private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authManager;

    public void before() throws Exception {
        this.authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "password");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(manager.authenticate(authentication));

    }

    @Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public void postExperience() throws Exception {
        ExperienceEntity experience = new ExperienceEntity();
        experience.setExperience("Test");
        experience.setExperienceEng("Test");

        mockMvc.perform(
                    post(URL_EXPERIENCES).principal(authentication).content(json(experience)).contentType(CONTENT_TYPE))
                    .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
        }
```

Error Log:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

I don't understand why this test don't work. I get these error, which I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem with exception type. You're expecting `AccessDeniedException`, but getting it wrapped in `NestedServletException`. To let your test be successful you can do it like so:

```
try {
    mockMvc.perform(post(URL_EXPERIENCES).principal(authentication)
        .content(json(experience)).contentType(CONTENT_TYPE))
        .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    Assert.fail();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Assert.assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof AccessDeniedException);
}
```

And remove `expected` property from your `@Test` annotation.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expectCause` to catch `NestedServletException`:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.ExpectedException;

public class AuthenticationIntegrationTest {

    @Rule public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void postExperience() throws Exception {
        // given
        ...

        // then
        thrown.expectCause(is(instanceOf(AccessDeniedException.class)));

        // or thrown.expectCause(isA(AccessDeniedException.class));

        // when
        mockMvc.perform(post(URL_EXPERIENCES).principal(authentication).content(json(experience))
                .contentType(CONTENT_TYPE))
                .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
}
```